# Ubuntu and Apache server

Tags: networking, server, apache2, proxy, domain-server

Not sure this is a Ubuntu question but try any way.
Today I have a NAS server. Needed a REAL server so yesterday I brought home my new PC with Ubuntu 16, Apache Server and Apache Traffic server (proxy). I live in Thailand and people who know how to install all this are very rare. I had a thai person do the install for me, but as expected far from everything works. I need to solve some problems before I can start configuring my self the best I can.
I connect this server to my NAS and on the same intranet I have a couple of PC's. They all work fine together.
I can connect from my new server to the NAS, Have two LAN ports
I can NOT connect from my new server to the NAS (Wrong internal IP configured may be)
I can NOT connect to internet from my new server, not through the NAS and not direct. I have a fixed incoming IP. (Wrong IP configured may be)
I do not know how to set/change those two IP's. I searched internet but probably do not know what to search on, because no info.
Thanks /Jan

Comment: How do you normally connect to the internet? Do you have a router, and if so, does it run DHCP or do you use static addresses? "I can connect from my new server to the NAS" - how exactly do you connect? How do you connect *through*  the NAS to Internet?

Comment: Can you make a [drawing](https://draw.io) of how things are connected and with IP's of the various interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer. I have discovered that the installation of Apache server and Apache traffic server, done by someone that looks like he do not know what he is doing. Same goes for me, but before I trouble you with more I will try to solve the basic problems first.